# How to accurately change a parsed version number in string form to numeric?

Tags: python

So say I have a retrieved directory name, "LibX_00.03", and I retrieve the version information of the directory with:

```py
lib = "LibX_00.03"

version = lib[-5:]
```

After doing this I then want to compare this version number with others to assert the latest release of the library, the trouble with this being that is has to be in a numberic form for comparison and not a str.
Casting to int or float both do not work, as int will give a whole number, and float gives an innacurate conversion:

```py
>>> float(version)
0.299999...
```

So how can I accurately preserve the version number while having it in a form where I make a comparison?

Comment: what value does version have?

Comment: As long as the naming convention is consistent, I would think that a simple string comparison would work ...

Comment: version has the value that was previously assigned to it in the first code snippet

Comment: @schacki true, although I am not the person responsible for updating the repository that contains the released versions of the libraries, so I would rather have a way that could work for any naming inconsistencies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> from distutils.version import StrictVersion
>>> StrictVersion('00.03') > StrictVersion('00.10')
False
>>> StrictVersion('00.03') > StrictVersion('00.02')
True
```

Note this won't work if you have `'1.0b'` as version string, for that use `LooseVersion`:

```
>>> from distutils.version import LooseVersion
>>> LooseVersion('1.2b') > LooseVersion('0.1')
True
>>> LooseVersion('1.2b') > LooseVersion('1.2c')
False
```

Comment: I was looking for this.  Sadly, it doesn't seem to be documented ( http://docs.python.org/distutils/apiref.html#module-distutils.version )

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you know that there will always be a format with 4 characters before the end. Why don't you trying something like this?

```
versionnumbers = [int(x) for x in version if x != '.']
```

Now you can access your list of version from highest to lowest.

```
versionnumbers[0] # Major
versionnumbers[1] # Minor
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Decimal` class from `decimal` module.

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> Decimal('00.03')
Decimal('0.03')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import decimal
>>> lib = "LibX_00.03"
>>> version=lib[-5:]
>>> dec=decimal.Decimal(version)
>>> dec
Decimal('0.03')

>>> 0.05>dec
False
>>> dec>decimal.Decimal('0.05')
False
>>> dec<decimal.Decimal('0.05')
True
>>> dec==decimal.Decimal('0.03')
True
>>> dec==decimal.Decimal('0.0299999999999999')
False
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on Aesthete's answer, which I find nice because you can custom-tailor it a bit more than the others, you can do the following:

```
>>> import re
>>> version = "00.13"
>>> nums = [ int(x) for x in re.split("\.",version) ]
>>> nums
[0, 13]
```

And `nums` will contain the `.` separated elements in your original version string. This is nice if you have version numbers greater than one character, like the `13` in my example instead of `03`.